# View all content inside win32 window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, window

I cannot see text/graphics at the very bottom of my win32 window, because it extends larger than my screen can fit. Even when I go in fullscreen mode, I cannot see the bottom text.

Is there a way for me to adjust my window or zoom-out of my window in order to see the stuff at the bottom? Or am I supposed to shrink all the contents inside the window?

I'm not exactly sure what I should do, but any guidance would be appreciated. Also I'm using C++.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much have two options:

- [Add a scrollbar](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/scrollbars-scrolling) (Adjust the window style or add a scrollbar control)
- Stretch/shrink/resize the content